# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') error in external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

There is a external JavaScript file and I am going to intert data list into html table. ArrayData is the list. when I run the file it gives an error "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')**". I reffered many same scenarios and still unable to solve this.

> [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

this also not solve my issue. the thing is I am writting html code in JavaScript file. most of questions answer when javascript write in html file.

Below is my external JavaScript file code

```
const newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Invoice No</th><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th></thead>";
var arrayLength = ArrayData.length;

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    const tdInvoiceNo = document.createElement("td");
    const tdProduct = document.createElement("td");
    const tdQuantity = document.createElement("td");
    tdInvoiceNo.textContent = ArrayData[i].invoiceNumber;
    tdProduct.textContent = ArrayData[i].productCode; 
    tdQuantity.textContent = ArrayData[i].quantity;
    newRow.appendChild(tdInvoiceNo);
    newRow.appendChild(tdProduct);
    newRow.appendChild(tdQuantity);
    newTable.appendChild(newRow);
}

const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(newTable);


str = str+"<div id="+'target'+"></div><br>";
```

Comment: Can you share the html file as well

Comment: there is no html file. html code also written in external javascript file.

Comment: looks like document.getElementById('target') cannot be found.

Comment: yeah. but below i create the tag "<div id="+'target'+"></div>";

Comment: @WCM If there is no html file, `document.getElementById('target')` will return undefined, unless this element is created using some other script and is executed before this script runs